# I just inherited an older, used Macbook Air and I'm cleaning it up for use. Why does HD only show 30 GB when it should be 121 GB? (See photo within.)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, storage, disk-space

As the title mentions, I received an older (Early 2014 MacBook Air OS X Yosemite) from my daughter when she bought a new MacBook. I'm not very knowledgeable on Macs but I know some basics.

The 'About this Mac' window shows the hard drive should be 121 GB, but looking at the storage, it appears I only have 30 GB available to me (I can't even explore the other 90 GB to see what is using the space).

I have attached a screenshot showing some information that will hopefully be useful.

Any help that can be provided in figuring out how to access the mystery 90 GB would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was able to get a different view of the Disk Utility by booting into macOS Recovery over the Internet, which gives it a newer-type view, including the circle graph. The 3rd and 4th pictures below are what I see when I choose the partition option on the Macintosh HD. You can see the 91.1 GB of "Free space", but it doesn't allow me to do anything with it, (despite the tool tip saying, "You may delete or resize this to allocate the space to preceding partition"), all the buttons are greyed out when I select that portion of the graph.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I included the Disk Utility list on the far left of the screenshot. I'm not sure exactly what to do to be able to access the other 90 GB.

Comment: What does Disk Utility say about the disk as a whole (should be a pie/circle graphic of some kind)?

Comment: Since Yosemite does not have SIP, you should be able to post the output from the command `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`. This command does not change your Mac. The command will show where the missing space is.

Comment: I just edited my question with screenshots of both the Disk Utility and the command output.

Comment: @nohillside: I should have pointed out that *"a pie/circle graphic of some kind"* did not start until El Capitan. Yosemite still used a rectangular box.

Comment: @nohillside I was able to get a different view of the Disk Utility by booting into macOS recovery over the internet, which gives it a newer-type view, including the circle graph. The 3rd and 4th pictures are what I see when I choose the partition option on the Macintosh HD. You can see the 91.1 GB of "Free space", but it doesn't allow me to do anything with it, (despite the tool tip saying, "You may delete or resize this to allocate the space to preceding partition"), all the buttons are greyed out when I select that portion of the graph.

Comment: @DavidAnderson My last comment may be of use to you as well, so I'm tagging you. Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: liveMike: Boot to Yosemite, open a Terminal application window and enter the  command `diskutil cs resizestack C54E7ECB-00DE-4183-A949-115F71B0C378  0B`.